# Unsupported class file major version 61

Tags: java, incompatibility, java-17, glowroot

I am trying to integrate [Glowroot](https://glowroot.org/) into my Java application. Unfortunately, I get the following error:

```
2022-05-13 09:25:57.777 ERROR o.g.a.w.PointcutClassFileTransformer - Unsupported class file major version 61
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 61
    at org.glowroot.agent.shaded.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:196)
```

Neither Glowroot nor my application seem to use gradle so I have no idea where this incompatibility is coming from.

Have you got any idea on how I could find the source of the incompatibility and then how I could fix it?

Thank you!

EDIT: I use Glowroot in the version 0.13.6 .

Second edit: Seems like the version of glowroot was the issue...

Comment: I downloaded file `glowroot-0.13.6-dist.zip` from **glowroot.org** and looked at the class file version for two files. Both were 50 which means they were compiled with Java 1.6

Comment: @StephenC It's just the bundled ASM from glowroot that doesn't know how to handle that class file version. No info about the JVM version is provided.

Comment: Was the problem: ASM was trying to access the Java 17 classes but couldn't. So a newer version of glowroot solved the problem?

Comment: @StephenC Given the error originates in `org.glowroot.agent.shaded.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader` it is more likely that that version of ASM doesn't support class version 61, rather than not running on Java 17. ASM needs to understand the class version to be able to modify its bytecode.

Comment: Change the dependency 
 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
     <version>5.2.9.RELEASE</version>
 </dependency>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(I incorrectly was zeroing in on the "Unsupported class file major version 61" message without looking at the stacktrace.)

The problem (as pointed out by @Mark Rotteveel) is that glowroot is failing while trying to do some code transformation using ASM.  Apparently the `ClassReader` in the version of ASM that is bundled in glowroot 0.13.6 doesn't understand version 61 (Java 17) class files.

Q: How to solve this?

A: Use glowroot 0.14.0-beta.2 or later; see https://github.com/glowroot/glowroot/issues/906.  Alternative, build your application and its dependencies (as required) for an earlier (target) version of Java, and (maybe<sup>1</sup>) run on an earlier version of Java.

---

<sup>1 - It depends on whether the code transformations involve the ASM `ClassReader` reading Java SE classes.</sup>

Answer (score 39):

## Also with Jacoco

This error also happens when upgrading to java 17 and having Jacoco 0.8.5. It may complain about some class file that cannot understand.

Just upgrade Jacoco to 0.8.8 or above and you are good to go.

Comment: thanks @manuelvigarcia
here i recheck it was a version issue for me. I used <version>0.8.8</version> for jacoco
https://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/changes.html

Comment: Thanks @manuelvigarcia, when migrating the spring-boot project from version 2.7.12 to 3.1.0 I had the same problem with jacoco. By updating the jacoco dependency to this 0.8.8 and the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 5):

The error "unsupported class file major version 61" just means that there's some library that's not supported for Java 17.
Read this to understand - https://mkyong.com/java/java-unsupported-class-file-major-version-61/

The stack trace above this error will tell you which dependency is that. You'll need to upgrade that dependency to the Java 17 compliant one.

Comment: This is often what the problem is.  But in THIS case, it isn't.  See my answer and the question comments.  Hint: you need to look *carefully* at the stacktrace!

Comment: QUOTE: "there's some library that's not supported for Java 17"

- wrong. You will get this error when you have compiled the class with Java 17(major version 17) and you are trying to run class file under lower java version (version 16 or below).

See https://java2blog.com/unsupported-class-file-major-version-61-java/

Answer (score 1):

Believe or not: for me the solution was just updating an IDE Jet Brains plugin, named `Package Search`. After clicking in the `Update` button that was appearing in the righter red rectangle showed in the screenshot, then restarting the IDE with the pop-up that shows in the right bottom corner after the update, the project started working normal and Gradle was able to import, and build everything normally again.

[image: ide_plugin_needed_to_update]