java agent throws UnsupportedClassVersionError when Instrumentation#retransformClasses is called
I'm trying to make a java agent to dump the caller of a method. I am using objectweb's ASM to transform the target method to invoke a function which dumps the caller and the internal state of the target method.
The agent is compiled under Java 11.0.20 (with gradle if that matters). It's being run via the -javaagent command flag. ASM version is 9.6.
The target jar is Bukkit-1.8.8, compiled under Java 8. However, I am running the bukkit jar under java 17, so the JVM should have no problems with understanding the agent jar.
Full log:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndStartAgent(InstrumentationImpl.java:491)
        at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndCallPremain(InstrumentationImpl.java:503)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError
        at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.retransformClasses0(Native Method)
        at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.retransformClasses(InstrumentationImpl.java:169)
        at me.cire3.sfbf.SFBFAgentEntryPoint.transform(SFBFAgentEntryPoint.java:39)
        at me.cire3.sfbf.SFBFAgentEntryPoint.premain(SFBFAgentEntryPoint.java:17)
        ... 6 more
*** java.lang.instrument ASSERTION FAILED ***: "!errorOutstanding" with message Outstanding error when calling method in invokeJavaAgentMainMethod at s\src\java.instrument\share\native\libinstrument\JPLISAgent.c line: 619
*** java.lang.instrument ASSERTION FAILED ***: "success" with message invokeJavaAgentMainMethod failed at s\src\java.instrument\share\native\libinstrument\JPLISAgent.c line: 459
*** java.lang.instrument ASSERTION FAILED ***: "result" with message agent load/premain call failed at s\src\java.instrument\share\native\libinstrument\JPLISAgent.c line: 422
FATAL ERROR in native method: processing of -javaagent failed, processJavaStart failed

Expected outcome: Agent writes the dump to a dump file.
Actual outcome: The whole thing crashes and burns.
This is not a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/72229157/139985 because my ASM version is updated & can handle jdk17 & jdk8.

Looks like a transformer transforms a class into something that is not supported by your JVM.

The error you are encountering typically occurs due to a mismatch between the version of Java used to compile your classes and the version used to run them.:
First, verify the version of Java installed on your system. Run the following command to check the version:
java -version
Ensure that the version displayed is compatible with the Java version used for compiling your code. If there's a mismatch, you may need to recompile your classes with the correct version.
You can specify the source and target versions during compilation using the javac command. For example, to compile with Java 11, use:
javac -source 11 -target 11 YourClass.java
This will ensure that both the source code and the generated bytecode are compatible with Java 11.

This isn't the issue, since if it was the UnsupportedClassVersionError would be thrown much earlier, during agent loading, instead of during the retransformClasses call
